# Does jQuery support apply CSS to newly created elements?

Tags: css, html-table, css-selectors

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
        $("#table tbody").append($("<tr>").append($("<td>").text("new")));
    });

            /*double-color effect*/
    $("#table tbody tr:even").css({"background":"lightgray"});
    $("#table tbody tr:odd").css({"background":"white"});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="click" />
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
        <tr><td>world</td></tr>
        <tr><td>I am here</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

I want the newly create `tr` elements also have double-color effect, but they don't, I want to know if jQuery can support applying CSS dynamically, just like `live()` or `on()` methods do? 
And I can also use `nth-child` selector, code like this:

```
  tr:nth-child(odd)
{
    background:lightgray;
}
tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background:white;
}
```

But just like [w3cschools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) said, it does not support IE8 and earlier version, I don't know whether the earlier versions of other major browsers like Chrome, Firefox and Safari also support this selector? So, is there a highly compatible way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#table tbody tr:even").css({"background":"lightgray"});
```

only changes the existing elements, it doesn't add a css rule. If you want it to apply to new elements, you'll have to execute it again after you added the elements. Simply put it in the event handler you give to the `click` function.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script tag as shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
        $("#table tbody").append($("<tr>").append($("<td>").text("new")));
        ApplyCss();
    });

   ApplyCss();
});

function ApplyCss() {
            /*double-color effect*/
    $("#table tbody tr:even").css({"background":"lightgray"});
    $("#table tbody tr:odd").css({"background":"white"});
}
</script>
```

This `ApplyCss()` function applies `css` once you appended new `tr` in `table`.